# How can I create many tables in my database using EF Core migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am doing a bookstore project and I first created one table for the adding book.
So I want to add login and signup pages and store to the database, but I am confused about how I can add another table or create tables related to my need using migrations. I have attached my `DbContext` class.

Forgive me my English is not so good. I am waiting for your answers. Thanks

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CODEwithZAKI.Data
{
    public class BookStoreContext : DbContext
    {
        public BookStoreContext(DbContextOptions<BookStoreContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[Dbcontext Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0BDO.png)

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: I have read it. but I want to how can I add more tables to my database using migration. how I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For how to add a new table to the database with ef core code first, you can follow the below steps:

1.Create your new table as a model

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    //other properties
}
```

2.Add its entry in DbContext class

```
public class BookStoreContext : DbContext
{
    public BookStoreContext(DbContextOptions<BookStoreContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Books> Books { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

3.Create a new migration with the addition of Posts in Package Manager Console

```
Add-Migration AuthorMigration
```

4.Update database

```
Update-Database
```

Answer (score 0):

To add new tables to you database using migrations is simply a matter of extending your `BookStoreContext` with the new sets and then running the migration commands. As an example using `dotnet` command.

Generate the new migration script:

```
dotnet ef migrations add DESCRIPTION_OF_YOUR_MIGRATION
```

Run the migration:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

And that's it. Everytime you add new records to your BookStoreContext you just go through the above two commands to run the EF Core migration process.

PS For login/authentication/identity it is recommended to utilize [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).